# How can I solve the Not found problem when getting from pytest-django through pk?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pytest, django-testing

I have a problem with django-pytest
I'm using, djnago-rest-framework
There is a problem testing the details. As shown in the code below, I entered the same details, detail1, detail2, and detail3 codes. However, only detail1 succeeds and detail2, detail3 indicates that ***'/api/v1/stats/1/' could not be found***. It also occurs when implementing delete. I am curious about the cause and solution of this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4Cio.png)

```
// tests/test_apis.py
import json
from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from stats.models import Stats


class StatsApiTests(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Stats.objects.get_or_create(blockshots=1, memo='test1')
        Stats.objects.get_or_create(blockshots=2, memo='test2')
        self.create_read_url = reverse('api:stats:stats-list')
        self.read_update_delete_url = reverse('api:stats:stats-detail', kwargs={'pk': '1'})

    def test_detail1(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.read_update_delete_url)
        data = json.loads(response.content)
        content = {
            'blockshots': 1,
            'memo': 'test1',
        }
        self.assertEqual(data, content)

    def test_detail2(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.read_update_delete_url)
        data = json.loads(response.content)
        content = {
            'blockshots': 1,
            'memo': 'test1',
        }
        self.assertEqual(data, content)

    def test_detail3(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.read_update_delete_url)
        data = json.loads(response.content)
        content = {
            'blockshots': 1,
            'memo': 'test1',
        }
        self.assertEqual(data, content)

    def test_list(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.create_read_url)
        self.assertContains(response, 'test1')
        self.assertContains(response, 'test2')
```

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to know what your actual implementation for `read_update_delete_url`, hence I assume it is looking up the resource by primary key. In that case, you can simply add the primary key in the url like this:

```
stat_one, _ = Stats.objects.get_or_create(blockshots=1, memo='test1')
stat_two, _ = Stats.objects.get_or_create(blockshots=2, memo='test2')

self.read_update_delete_url = reverse('api:stats:stats-detail', kwargs={'pk': stat_one.pk})
```

Basically, [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) returns the object and the state of the object (created or not). You can use the object's id as the parameter of `reverse` function.

Comment: Oh, god... You saved my life. I did what you was told, and the problem was solved. I heartily thank you. Can I ask you one more question? What does stat_one, _ mean?